# Harry Potter Ditloids

Tags: knowledge, literature

Each of the 15 lines below [represent a phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditloid) related to Harry Potter.

For example:

$$\text{1994 I W the W C} = \text{1994 Ireland Wins the World Cup}$$

Can you figure out the rest?

$$\text{150 P for the G S}$$
$$\text{P 9 and 3 Q}$$
$$\text{29 K in a S}$$
$$\text{687 is H G V}$$
$$\text{4 C in the T T}$$
$$\text{7 M on a Q T}$$
$$\text{N 4 P D}$$
$$\text{B of the 7 P}$$
$$\text{12 U of D B}$$
$$\text{3 D H}$$
$$\text{7 H of V}$$
$$\text{12 G P}$$
$$\text{142 S at H}$$
$$\text{9 H on the W C}$$
$$\text{12 F S W to C W}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solutions to all 15 Ditloids as follows:

> **150 Points for the Golden Snitch** (a ball in the magical sport of quidditch)
>
>  **Platform 9 and 3 Quarters** (the magical extra platform at Kings Cross station, from where you can catch the Hogwarts Express)
>
>  **29 Knuts in a Sickle** (magical currency)
>
>  **687 is Harry’s Gringotts Vault** (at the bank in Diagon Alley)
>
>  **4 Champions in the Triwizard Tournament** (in Harry's fourth year at least - normally there are only 3 contestants in this international tournament for students of magic...)
>
>  **7 Members on a Quidditch Team** (1 keeper, 3 chasers, 2 beaters, 1 seeker - not 'Men' note, as women can play quidditch too!)
>
>  **Number 4 Privet Drive** (address of the Dursleys, Harry's last remaining relatives)
>
>  **Battle of the 7 Potters** (an episode in Book 7)
>
>  **12 Uses of Dragon’s Blood** (famed work of Albus Dumbledore and Nicholas Flamel)
>
>  **3 Deathly Hallows** (the Elder Wand, the Resurrection Stone, and a certain Cloak of Invisibility...)
>
>  **7 Horcruxes of Voldemort** (best not to ask...)
>
>  **12 Grimmauld Place** (headquarters for the Order of the Phoenix)
>
>  **142 Staircases at Hogwarts** (a fact mentioned in the book)
>
>  **9 Hands on the Weasleys' Clock** (which tells not the time but the locations of the 9 Weasley family members)
>
>  **12 Fail-Safe Ways to Charm Witches** (book, a gift to Harry on his 17th birthday by Ron Weasley)

Comment: Great job! Note: #6 - I had a different word in mind for M, but this works too. #13 - One of the words is not correct.

Comment: @eyl327 Ah yes - corrected both! :)